# How to save the R output?

Tags: r

I have the following script in R. The script runs and gives the output. But the file does not save. How can I save the output?

```
write.table(paste(main_root,"quan_2012_12_",j,"_",6*i,"<-y^2",sep=""))
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the `?write.table`

> write.table(x, file = "", append = FALSE, quote = TRUE, sep = " ",
>               eol = "\n", na = "NA", dec = ".", row.names = TRUE,
>               col.names = TRUE, qmethod = c("escape", "double"),
>               fileEncoding = "")

In the OP's code, there is only the `file` part, so it is better to provide the 'x' or the object name

```
write.table(x=yourObject, file= filename)
```

and the other arguments as needed.

Comment: I tried this:write.table(y,file="quan_2012_12_",j,"_",6*i,sep=""). Got error: Error in write.table(y, file = "quan_2012_12_", j, "_", 6 * i, sep = "") : 
  invalid 'quote' specification. Here i and j are two loops.

Comment: @userss What is `j` and `i`?  Is it a loop?  In that case, you have to use `lapply` or `for` loop

Comment: I used i and j as a loop ,,, I can get the output, only the problem is with saving the file...

Comment: @userss Without you showing the full code and update your post, it is not easy for others

Comment: you didn't specify the file name correctly, according to your comment `write.table(y,file="quan_2012_12_",j,"",6*i,sep="")` is being interpreted as `write.table(y,file="quan_2012_12_", append = j, quote = "", eol = 6*i, sep="")`. maybe try this `write.table(y,file=paste("quan_2012_12_",j,"",6*i,sep=""))` or, to save typing `write.table(y,file= paste0("quan_2012_12_",j,6*i))`